# PrinterJob archive tif or tiff

Tags: java, swing

PrinterJob someone used to print the file. tif or. tiff? . jpg. png it prints normally. But the file. Tif does not print, it generates a blank pdf. Can anyone tell me what can I do?

```
public void print(File arquivo, int copias)
{
    try
    {
        setFile(arquivo);

        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this, job.defaultPage());
        job.setJobName("Print-" + arquivo.getName());
        job.setCopies(copias);

        Book b = new Book();
        b.append(this, job.defaultPage());

        job.setPageable(b);

        if (job.printDialog())
        {
            job.print();
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1567457/230513).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with ITextPDF, found this link http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=184 transforming TIFF in PDF. After this, PrintHelper was used for print, thank you all.